# Redirect wordpress specific attachment_id URL with question mark

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have checked all asked questions, but nothing resolved my problem.

There is a URL https://www.example.com/blog/?attachment_id=3392 which redirects to 404 not found page. I have many of these attachment_id URLs which needs to be redirected to https://www.example.com/blog/ for example. How can I do it with htaccess redirect ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?attachment_id(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt help. Still 404 when I'm trying to access https://www.example.com/blog/?attachment_id=3392

Comment: You could create a redirect in the 404 template page. If it contacts that string create a redirect to /blog